# How to pass Id in a encrypted format to public site in Salesforce?

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, force.com-sites, security

I have created a public site where a VF page is exposed with a few URL parameter ( Id of a few objects ). Now I want to encrypt those Ids so that there is no security risk.

I was trying to achieve it using Crypto class but the moment I am adding below lines of code in my class, it's asking me to log in.

```java
Blob exampleIv = Blob.valueOf('Example of IV123');
Blob key = Crypto.generateAesKey(128);
Blob data = Blob.valueOf(param);
Blob encrypted = Crypto.encrypt('AES128', key, exampleIv, data);
```

or this

```java
Blob key = Crypto.generateAesKey(128);
Blob data = Blob.valueOf(param);
Blob encrypted = Crypto.encryptwithManagedIV('AES128', key, data);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends a little whether you just need a token you can query for in a separate field, or something you can actually decrypt and read the id
Assuming the latter, you need to create a key, store it somewhere and then use it to encrypt and decrypt
e.g. create a key that is the right length and store the string somewhere safe:

```
Datetime dt = system.now();
String s = string.valueof(dt);
String s2 = s.replaceAll('\\D','');
String sKey = userinfo.getOrganizationId() +s2;
```

Encrypt the Id replace [MyId] with your Id to encrypt:

```
 Blob sKeyBLob = blob.valueOf(sKey);
 Blob cipherText = Crypto.encryptWithManagedIV('AES256', sKeyBLob, Blob.valueOf([MyId]));
 String encodedCipherText = EncodingUtil.convertToHex(cipherText); 
 String encodedId = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(encodedCipherText,'UTF-8') ;
 system.debug('encoded version' + encodedId);
```

Pass Id to the VF page - and then you take the parameter e.g. sEncryptedId and decrypt using the same key

```
 Blob sKeyBLob2 = blob.valueOf(sKey);
String sCleanLink = EncodingUtil.urlDecode(sEncryptedId,'UTF-8');
 Blob encodedEncryptedBlob = EncodingUtil.convertFromHex(sCleanLink);
 Blob decryptedBlob = Crypto.decryptWithManagedIV('AES256', sKeyBLob2, encodedEncryptedBlob);
 String decryptedId = decryptedBlob.toString();
 system.debug('decryptedId' + decryptedId);
```

decryptedId should be the original version of the Id

Comment: I am getting the same message. Authorization Required.

Comment: Authorization Required means the site is throwing an error, so you need to setup a debug log for that Guest Site user so you can then what the error is

Comment: I was assigning the encrypted String to an Id variable that's why it was throwing an error. It's working now. Thanks a lot.